# Multidimensional array search in Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, thymeleaf

Is it possible to check if a specific element exists on a 2D array?

```
<div th:each="employee, i : ${company.employees}">
<div th:each="duty, j : ${employee.duties}">
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox my-1 mr-sm-2">
        <input type="checkbox" name="duties"
               th:id="${j.index}" th:value="${j.index}"
               th:checked="${#arrays.contains(${company.tasks[i.index][]}, ${duty.id})}" />
        <label th:for="${j.index}" th:text="${j.index}"></label>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The Java equivalent should be:

```
for (int i=0; i<company.getEmployees().length; i++)
    for (Duty duty : company.getEmployees().[i].getDuties())
       boolean checked = company.getTasks()[i].contains(duty.id); 
       // Contains, method that checks whether element exists on array
```

Comment: clearify what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do that!

Thymeleaf with other front-end frameworks is not suitable for the data extraction and transformation which should be performed 1 or 2 layers lower. The role of these frameworks is to bind, publish and display an already transformed model which should be in the best case already in its final form.

I suggest you perform this conditional data extraction before you expose the data to the template. The only one iteration will be needed inside the template.